# Regular Expression to match index.html, index.htm, default.html, default.htm

Tags: php, regex

I'm retrieving a set of files from a certain folder, and I want to detect if each file is named index.html, index.htm, default.html, default.htm etc. Instead of a clumsy line that says

`if($file=='index.html || $file=='index.htm' || $file=='INDEX.HTML')`

I'd rather use a proper regular expression to match uppercase/lowercase variations etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
if (preg_match('/^(index|default)\.html?$/i', $file)) {
    echo 'file matches';
}
```

Comment: Does this take into account html OR htm?

Comment: @SubjectX it will match both.

Comment: Can u quickly explain which part of expression says HTML and HTM? So, which part takes away L from matching pattern?

Comment: @SubjectX the `?` marks the preceding character as optional. You can read more about it (and others) here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 5):

Is it really worth it? A regex is harder to read for other people working on the code, so you would end up explaining it in comments, taking up more space than the original solution.

Why not do a `strtolower()` and a normal comparison, maybe abbreviated by using `in_array()`?

Like e.g.

```
$names = array("index.htm", "index.html", "default.html", "default.htm");

if (in_array($file, $names))
 // do stuff
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. That'll teach me to waste time looking up Jamie Zawinski's quotes.

Comment: Nice idea. Perfetly fits for this case.